# How to resolve the System.TypeInitializationException at initializing the CrystalReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have initialized the CrystalReportViewer in constructor of a form. While compiling the sample, I get the below exception from the initialization of the CrystalReportViewer.

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ReportSourceFactory' threw an
>   exception.' TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception.

I have included the log4net assembly from nuget.org and tried to resolve this by setting the framework as 4.0 and the platform type as x86 which are suggested from the below link,
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/178150/The-type-or-namespace-name-CrystalDecisions-could

However,it does not help to resolve the issue.

Code of CrystalReportViewer

```
this.CrystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalReportViewer();
this.CrystalReportViewer1.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
this.CrystalReportViewer1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
this.CrystalReportViewer1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
this.CrystalReportViewer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.CrystalReportViewer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.CrystalReportViewer1.Name = "CrystalReportViewer1";
this.CrystalReportViewer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(808, 504);
this.CrystalReportViewer1.TabIndex = 0;
this.Controls.Add(CrystalReportViewer1);
```

sample link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bA4VMK1ifevE1vRsvOiEqYaGku-C7U24/view?usp=sharing

Can anyone provide a solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? It seems that it might be a solution to change the Target Platform from Any CPU to x64 or x86, did you try that?